# load external js file into bootstrap modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show google map in bootstrap modal box. I load google map API from google site in my page and modal box worked. Like This :

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

HTML :

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
```

Now, I need to load google map api(`.JS File`/`Libraries`) from url after click link (launch Modal) of modal box. How to create this ?

Comment: There is a tutorial for this found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial - Pretty much you need to just add a div into your modal.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast: I need to load external `.js` File! not Show Google map into div.

Comment: Why can't you simply use `<script src="yourfilehere.js"></script>`?

Comment: You need to load the external google map api or you need to load the initialize class? Because you are already loading the google map api with the above line...

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Load external Google map Api(`.js`) file.

Comment: @doitmyway: google map api is Big File! I need to load `js` file if I need to show google map.

Comment: If you're willing to use jQuery, you might want to look into this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, then you could use the `jQuery.getScript()` method: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Basic usage:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```